# Вывод ссылок в шаблоне Django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос... Как отобразить ссылку в браузере так, что бы фильтр urlize в шаблоне не трогал уже готовые ссылки, завернутые в тег `<a></a>`? В шаблон подается текст из БД, который содержит ссылки в виде `<a> href="www.link.com">Clik!</a>` и ссылки как просто текст в виде [www.link.com](http://www.link.com), **нужно что бы фильтр urlize не трогал ссылку в теге, а работал только с текстовой ссылкой**